# A postive, decreasing function $f$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln f(n) / \ln n$ neither diverges nor converges to $-\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Is there a positive, decreasing function $f$ such that 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln f(n)}{\ln n}
$$
neither converges nor diverges to $-\infty$?

One candidate is a function like 
$$
f(n) = e^{-(\ln n)(\sin n)}.
$$
But I don't think this function is decreasing. Similar functions I've tried have the same issue.

Comment: A positive decreasing function is automatically bounded.

Comment: And it would converge to the LUB of {$f(n)$}

Comment: But $\ln f(n)$ need not be bounded!

Comment: @copper.hat - Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can let $\frac{\ln f(n)}{\ln n}$ oscillate: If $f(n)=\frac1n$, then  $\frac{\ln f(n)}{\ln n}=-1$, and if $f(n)=\frac1{n^2}$, then  $\frac{\ln f(n)}{\ln n}=-2$.
So have a look at a recursion such as
$$ f(n)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if } n=1\\\tfrac1{n^2}&\text{if }f(n-1)>\tfrac1n\\
f(n-1)&\text{if } f(n-1)\le \tfrac1n\end{cases}$$
(Exercise: Write down an explicit formula for $f$ using logs, exponentials and the floor function)

Comment: If $n_k = k^2$, $\displaystyle{\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}} \ln f(n_k) / \ln n_k = -1$.  If  $n_k = k^2 + 1$, $\displaystyle{\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}} \ln f(n_k) / \ln n_k = -2$. Therefore $\displaystyle{\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}} \ln f(n) / \ln n \leq -2 < -1 \leq \displaystyle{\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}} \ln f(n) / \ln n$.